# Laravel Eloquent relationship error

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 for my blog. But when I use relation "hasMany", I got following error "FatalErrorException in 45abc28f0139bedaa1467307304d448ffaaed95e.php line 5: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) "

Here is my PostController

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\View;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Post;


 class PostController extends Controller
{
public function index(){
    $listePosts = Post::all();

    return view('post.index', compact('listePosts'));
}

public function show($detail){
    $post = Post::where('detail', $detail)->firstOrFail();
    $author = $post->user;
    $comment = $post->comments;

    return view('post.show', compact('post', 'author', 'comment'));



 }
 }

 ?>
```

Here is my Post Model

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



class Post extends Model
{
protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at'];

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
}
```

And here is my User Model

```
<?php

 namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


 class User extends Authenticatable
 {
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at'];

protected $fillable = [
    'user_full_name', 'user_pseudo', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];


public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
 }
```

Please, how can I solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's the bit causing the problem?

Comment: I think, because when I write for a example return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'Post'); I get error that a colum comments.Comment is not found

Comment: `"I get error that a colum comments.Comment is not found"` - surely that's your problem?

Comment: While reading docs, it would be just as I wrote it on my code. But when I got (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) error, I complete a second parameter for method hasMany and then, it present another error which is column not found. But I think, that the first error come in syntax error in relationship. Or how can I use find() method in my PostController@show function to get the same result as expected normally. Thanks

Comment: can you add content of your view, because the error is not in controller the above error says its in view 'post.show' so post content of post/show.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

here is my show.blade.php source code

```
@extends('template')

@section('content')

<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h2 class="panel-title" align="center">{{post->post_name}}</h2>
    <h3> Créé par : {{author->user_pseudo}} |
        @if (post->count_comments == 0)
            Pas de commentaire
        @elseif (post->count_comments == 1)
            1 Commentaire
        @else 
            {{ post->count_comments}} Commentaires
        @endif


    </h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <p>{{post->content}}</p>

    <div>
        <h2 class="label label-info">Les commentaires</h2>
        @foreach($comment as $oneComment)
            <h4>Posté par : {{ $oneComment->user->user_pseudo}}</h4>
            <p>{{ $oneComment->content}}</p>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>  
  </div>
  @stop
```